# Activate Checkbox Based upon Drop Down Value

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I am looking for a solution in Javascript that would enable (place the check in it) a checkbox on a form, based upon a specific drop-down value (in standard HTML, generated by SQL) being selected elsewhere on the same form.  I've not written any code yet, so don't have any to show here at this time.  EDIT on 04/08/20: Based upon the excellent help received from Giuliano, I decided to add the code that I put together, (which is not working), as follows:

```
<%
sSQL = "SELECT OrderTypeID, OrderTypeString FROM LookupOrderTypesII"
Set rsOrderTypes = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsOrderTypes.Open sSQL, oConnGlobal, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly 
iTotalRecords = rsOrderTypes.Recordcount

If iTotalRecords > 0 Then
%>

<br>
<b>SERVICE/ORDER TYPE:</b>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let select = document.getElementById("cboOrderType");
    let checkbox = document.getElementById("chkSkipVenueEventDetails");

        select.addEventListener("change", function () {
        checkbox.checked = select.value == "12|LABOR SALES/PAYMENT";
        });
</script>

<select class="rounded" name="cboOrderType" id="cboOrderType">
    <option value="Select One" selected>Select One</option>
    <option value="-9999" <%=IfSelected(iOrderTypeID, "Not Listed-ADD Custom Type")%>>Not Listed-ADD Custom Type</option>
    <%
        Do While Not rsOrderTypes.EOF 

            iOrderTypeID = Trim(rsOrderTypes("OrderTypeID"))
            sOrderTypeString = Trim(rsOrderTypes("OrderTypeString"))
    %>
        <option value="<%=iOrderTypeID%>|<%=sOrderTypeString%>"<%=IfSelected(sOrderTypeString, sOrderTypeString_NewRequest)%>><%=sOrderTypeString%></option>
    <%
        rsOrderTypes.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
</select>
<% 
    rsOrderTypes.Close
    Set rsOrderTypes = Nothing

End If
%>
'''

The SQL code generates the following code (as viewed in browser source):

'''
<select class="rounded" name="cboOrderType" id="cboOrderType">
    <option value="Select One" selected>Select One</option>
    <option value="-9999" >Not Listed-ADD Custom Type</option>
    <option value="1|WILL CALL">WILL CALL</option>
    <option value="2|DELIVERY ONLY-CUSTOMER RETURN">DELIVERY ONLY-CUSTOMER RETURN</option>
    <option value="3|DELIVERY and PICKUP ONLY (Dry Hire)">DELIVERY and PICKUP ONLY (Dry Hire)</option>
    <option value="4|DELIVERY with SETUP and STRIKE">DELIVERY with SETUP and STRIKE</option>
    <option value="5|DELIVERY with SETUP ONLY-CUSTOMER STRIKES">DELIVERY with SETUP ONLY-CUSTOMER STRIKES</option>
    <option value="6|SHIPPED-CUSTOMER RETURN">SHIPPED-CUSTOMER RETURN</option>
    <option value="7|SUPERVISION ONLY">SUPERVISION ONLY</option>
    <option value="8|CONSULTATION SERVICES">CONSULTATION SERVICES</option>
    <option value="9|EQUIPMENT SALES-WILL CALL">EQUIPMENT SALES-WILL CALL</option>
    <option value="10|EQUIPMENT SALES-SHIPPED">EQUIPMENT SALES-SHIPPED</option>
    <option value="11|COMMISSION SALES">COMMISSION SALES</option>
    <option value="99|TEST ORDER">TEST ORDER</option>
    <option value="12|LABOR SALES/PAYMENT">LABOR SALES/PAYMENT</option>
</select>
```

And here is the checkbox HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkSkipVenueEventDetails" id="chkSkipVenueEventDetails">&nbsp;<strong>Skip Venue & Event Details</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: I was banned from answering questions, and was informed by Stack Overflow to improve upon this question (and another one), so that I can ask questions again.  I did exactly that by adding all of the code that I put together, yet it did nothing to cause this down vote to go away.  And I can't even see who down-voted it.  This is very frustrating.  Can the person that did this, at least please contact me via email and let me know what I need to do to get this down vote removed?  This is affecting my way of living, which is very meager at this time due to COVID-19.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add an event listener to the "change" event of the select and based on the value that is selected you can change the attribute "checked" of the checkbox

html:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <select id="select">
   <option value="a" selected>something</option>
   <option value="b">check</option>
  </select>
  <label>
   <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
   Checkbox
  </label>
  <script>
   let select = document.getElementById("select");
   let checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
   select.addEventListener("change", function () {
     checkbox.checked = select.value !== "a";
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Try it](https://codepen.io/elitexxl/pen/RwPOwaw)

Comment: Hello Giuliano.  Thank you very much for this!  It's my fault for not explaining myself clearly in my original question.  I am actually trying to check the checkbox, not enable or disable its ability to be used.  Also, I cut and past your code directly into a new HTML page to test it, and it doesn't work.  I surrounded the JS code with <script> brackets, but to no avail.  It DOES work on Try It, but not in an actual HTML page.

Comment: I updated the answer (the codepen too), now it does what you need, if I understand correctly. Hope this helps. (BTW the first code didn't work because I forgot the id on the select element)

Comment: Yes!  It now works exactly as I described.  Thank you very much!  I didn't see the ID mistake until you mentioned it.  Why did it work in Fiddle?  I just don't understand why somebody down-voted me for asking this question.  It makes me not want to ask them.  I have a great deal of knowledge about coding, having been a coder for over 30-years now, but I can't ever get enough points to get anywhere.

Comment: Great! It did work in the Fiddle, because there I didn't make that mistake. However I think that someone downvoted this question because it is very basic and with a bit of googling you could find the answer by yourself. And well, I'm glad to be helpful even if I understand doing so, maybe it would be better commenting your question and not downvoting only, as happened to me sometimes. It is important also search the website for a possible duplicate. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your input Giuliano.  It is most appreciated.  Unfortunately, there are those of us whom even the most basic code is difficult, when it is outside our normal expertise.  I am primarily a SQL and VB developer, disciplines that do not require the use of Javascript on a regular basis, if at all.  And yes, I did Google this question and searched for an answer for several hours, before placing a question here.  And as well, I really want to get used to using this site.  I don't think a person should be down-voted for not having the skills yet on any subject matter.

Comment: I tried to implement your code into the page that I am working on, and unfortunately it did not work.  Therefore, I have included the code that I put together, for review.

Comment: You should put the script tag after the select tag, otherwise it will be run before the select tag is created

Comment: Hello Giuliano, I finally got it all working, but I had to add  a $(document).ready(function() { }; surrounding the javascript code, and also put it AFTER the checkbox HTML.  I think this is due to the way that server code is loaded and possibly due to buffering being turned on.  I'll experiment a bit more, and provide more information as I work through the code.  The page this is being used on has over 12,000 lines of code, so is extremely complex.